# How to set selection mode for images? C# in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am creating Image gallery with image editor in it. In my project there are 2 forms: Form1 - gallery, where you can upload and then choose which image to edit. Form2 - editor itself.
How to make pictures selectable in Form1, so that I could send selected picture to Form2?

First I tried it with radio buttons, while taking images from resources in project itself. It worked, but editor functions wouldn't run in this case.

Comment: How about passing the path to the image as a parameter in the constructor of the form2.

Answer (score 0):

To make an image selectable, you need to add it to a control such as PictureBox

```
PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.Image = imagem;
        pictureBox.MouseClick += this.pictureBox_MouseClick;
```

Then configure the Picture Box Click Event to open the new form by sending the image in the form's constructor method

```
private void pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pictureBoxClicked = (PictureBox)sender;
        FormEditor frmEditor = new FormEditor(pictureBoxClicked.Image);
        frmEditor.ShowDialog();
    }
```